# Cannot get rid of Fatal Exception: NSInternalInconsistencyException Error

Tags: ios, swift, crash

```
Fatal Exception: NSInternalInconsistencyException
Application windows are expected to have a root view controller at the end of application launch
-[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:]
```

**Crash Report**

```
Fatal Exception: NSInternalInconsistencyException
    0  ???                            0x184066d8c (Missing)
    1  ???                            0x1832205ec (Missing)
    2  ???                            0x184066bf8 (Missing)
    3  ???                            0x184a56fa0 (Missing)
    4  UIKit                          0x18dc42a80 -[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:]
    5  UIKit                          0x18e272b1c __111-[__UICanvasLifecycleMonitor_Compatability _scheduleFirstCommitForScene:transition:firstActivation:completion:]_block_invoke
    6  UIKit                          0x18dc41dd0 +[_UICanvas _enqueuePostSettingUpdateTransactionBlock:]
    7  UIKit                          0x18dc41c6c -[__UICanvasLifecycleMonitor_Compatability _scheduleFirstCommitForScene:transition:firstActivation:completion:]
    8  UIKit                          0x18dc40afc -[__UICanvasLifecycleMonitor_Compatability activateEventsOnly:withContext:completion:]
    9  UIKit                          0x18e8d684c __82-[_UIApplicationCanvas _transitionLifecycleStateWithTransitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke
    10 UIKit                          0x18dc401ec -[_UIApplicationCanvas _transitionLifecycleStateWithTransitionContext:completion:]
    11 UIKit                          0x18e6bbac8 __125-[_UICanvasLifecycleSettingsDiffAction performActionsForCanvas:withUpdatedScene:settingsDiff:fromSettings:transitionContext:]_block_invoke
    12 UIKit                          0x18e809bf8 _performActionsWithDelayForTransitionContext
    13 UIKit                          0x18dc3fc0c -[_UICanvasLifecycleSettingsDiffAction performActionsForCanvas:withUpdatedScene:settingsDiff:fromSettings:transitionContext:]
    14 UIKit                          0x18dc3f5a8 -[_UICanvas scene:didUpdateWithDiff:transitionContext:completion:]
    15 UIKit                          0x18dc3c5e0 -[UIApplication workspace:didCreateScene:withTransitionContext:completion:]
    16 UIKit                          0x18dc3c330 -[UIApplicationSceneClientAgent scene:didInitializeWithEvent:completion:]
```

Crash report header is

```
UIKit
-[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:]
```

**applicationDidFinishLaunching**

```
if (launchOptions == nil) {
    if (TegKeychain.get("ISLOGGEDIN") == "1") {
        heartbeat()
        let initialViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "WelcomeTab")
        self.window?.rootViewController = initialViewController
        self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    } else {
        let initialViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Entrance")
        self.window?.rootViewController = initialViewController
        self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    }
} else {
    if let notifications = launchOptions?[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey.remoteNotification] as? [String: AnyObject] {
        heartbeat()

        if let type = notifications["type"] as? String
        {
            if type == "msg" {
                if let userID = notifications["userID"] as? String {
                    userDefaults.set(userID, forKey: "goToChat")
                }

                let initialViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "WelcomeTab")
                self.window?.rootViewController = initialViewController
                self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

                if let tabBarController = self.window!.rootViewController as? UITabBarController {
                    tabBarController.selectedIndex = 3
                }
            }

            if type == "follow" {
                if let userID = notifications["userID"] as? String {
                    userDefaults.set(userID, forKey: "goToProfile")
                }
                let initialViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "WelcomeTab")
                self.window?.rootViewController = initialViewController
                self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

                if let tabBarController = self.window!.rootViewController as? UITabBarController {
                    tabBarController.selectedIndex = 0
                }
            }

            if type == "attend" {
                if let eventID = notifications["eventID"] as? String {
                    userDefaults.set(eventID, forKey: "goToEvent")
                }
                let initialViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "WelcomeTab")
                self.window?.rootViewController = initialViewController
                self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

                if let tabBarController = self.window!.rootViewController as? UITabBarController {
                    tabBarController.selectedIndex = 0
                }
            }
        }
    }

    if let _ = launchOptions?[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey.location] {
        startSignificationLocation()
    }
}
```

What is that crash and how can I get rid of it?

Comment: If you don't pass `if let type = notifications["type"] as? String`, are you really setting a rootViewController? Could you add prints/breakpoint to see where your execution go exactly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your application delegate is not setting the `rootViewController` property of the main UIWindow before `applicationDidFinishLaunching` completes. This is typically set up for you in all the Xcode templates. If you create your own window, make sure to set its root view controller immediately.

As rmaddy notes, in your code, if `launchOptions` is set, but `launchOptions?[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey.remoteNotification] as? [String: AnyObject]` returns nil, then `rootViewController` is never set. If `notifications["type"] as? String` is nil, `rootViewController` is never set. If the type is something other than the three values you expect, `rootViewController` is never set.

`rootViewController` must be set before this method finishes, or the app will crash. You need to cover all possible ways the app can launch. There is no promised list of every possible way an app can launch, so you're going to need some kind of fallback when it launches in a way that you're not expecting (or else "the app crashes" is the behavior you're requesting in that case).

Comment: I edited the question and added my applicationDidFinishLaunching

Comment: @UtkuDalmaz And in the code you posted, there are several code paths that result in no rootViewController being set.

Comment: @rmaddy should I set rootviewcontroller also if UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey.location is set?

Comment: You must always set `rootViewController`.